# Question about Bluetooth Low Energy connection event

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm searching for some information about BLE and this question didn't find an answer. For the first connection between a master and a slave, it should be an exchange of keys, for encrypting. But for the next connection events, is it the same key or each connection event has its own key?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

BLE uses AES-CCM. Why don't you take a look at the Bluetooth Core specification Vol 6, Part E where this is described?

When encryption is started, the bonding key plus some random numbers supplied by both devices are used to derive a session key that AES-CCM will use. I'm not sure what you really are trying to figure out, but CCM uses a packet counter. This means every packet will be encrypted differently even if it contains the same data.